# Performance for myCollection.Add() vs. myCollection["key"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, collections, key-value

When dealing with a collection of key/value pairs is there any difference between using its Add() method and directly assigning it?

For example, a HtmlGenericControl will have an Attributes Collection:

```
var anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");

// These both work:
anchor.Attributes.Add("class", "xyz");
anchor.Attributes["class"] = "xyz";
```

Is it purely a matter of preference, or is there a reason for doing one or the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are equivalent for your use, in this case, running this:

```
anchor.Attributes["class"] = "xyz";
```

Actually calls this internally:

```
anchor.Attributes.Add("class", "xyz");
```

In `AttributeCollection` the `this[string key]` setter looks like this:

```
public string this[string key]
{
  get { }
  set { this.Add(key, value); }
}
```

So to answer the question, **in the case of `AttributeCollection`**, it's just a matter of preference.  Keep in mind, this isn't true for other collection types, for example `Dictionary<T, TValue>`.  In this case `["class"] = "xyz"` would update or set the value, where `.Add("class", "xyz")` (if it already had a `"class"` entry) would throw a duplicate entry error.

Comment: This is true for AttributeCollection, but not necessarily true for all key-value collection types (NameValueCollection comes to mind)

Comment: @Jimmy - Correct, I'll amend to give an example.

Comment: @Jimmy: I did a quick NameValueConfigurationCollection. They seem "functionally" the same. Is it a performance difference? @Nick: Yes, in this case, I was using an AttributeCollection when I wondered if there was a difference.

Comment: @Atomiton: I meant System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection,  which is a multimap -- d.Add("foo", "bar"); d.Add("foo", "baz") yields d["foo"] = "bar,baz";

Comment: @Jimmy: Thanks for the example. That makes sense. The edited answer is much improved, too.